# Algorithm to reorder multiple non-adjacent elements in array to specific index

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I've been trying to rack my head over this but it's just not working.

I'm using some proprietary technology that only allows the move of a single element at a time. Super annoying. Think of it as list.moveRow(before, after).

So imagine a todo list with 10 items in it: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`

What I want to do is reorder multiple items in there, 
so say I select items `2, 6, 7, and 8`.

Then I drag and drop to position `4`.

The idea is that the elements would now be in order: `1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 9, 10`.

Is there a simple way to do this? I tried using extra variables to keep track of offsets due to an element moved that throws off the index, but it's super messy. :(

Comment: Check out the "splice" command - this will let you insert an array of "selected" items, into a specific place in your array.

Comment: Hey @Daniel, sadly I'm using an API that only allows the move of a single element at a time. Super annoying. Think of it as list.moveRow(before, after). T_T

Comment: Will you be making multiple moves or will the drag and drop occur only once?

Comment: Have to allow for multiple moves.

Comment: @Carlin - I have no CLUE why I thought you were talking about JS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sat down and wrote it out, and came up with a reasonable solution. This seems to work fine:

```
// Reorder list
function reorder(items, index)
{        
    // When we move, we have to account for previously moved rows too
    //  Go from bottom-most selected row first to preserve order
    for (var i = items.length - 1, itemOffset = 0, indexOffset = 0; i >= 0; --i) 
    {
        // Move
        list.moveRow(items[i] + itemOffset, index + indexOffset);

        // Change offsets based on location
        //  If next row index is after target index, add to row offset
        if (i-1 >= 0 && items[i-1] >= index) {
            itemOffset++;
        } else {    // If next index is before target, subtract from target
            itemOffset= 0;
            indexOffset--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the language.

Supposing you have a simple way to get isSelected() for each item, the simplest and most generic seems to be to build a new array as a list (that is adding from the first index to the last one) :

- add in order the non selected items until position of insert
- add the selected items
- add the remaining unselected items

And after that replace old array.

In pseudo code :

```
func(int[] items, bool[] isselected, int insertpos) {
   newitems = new int[items.length]
   i=0
   for (j=0; j<items.length; j++) {
      if j==insertpos {
          for (k=0; k<items.length; k++) {
              if isselected[k] {
                  newitems[i++] = items[k]
              }
          }
      } else if !isselected[j] {
          newitems[i++] = items[j]
      }
   }
   return newitems
}
```

If you want high performance and in place modification... that's another matter...

Comment: Added a pseudo code version. Tested nothing and maybe I missed an index but it should be clearer with it.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I found this sooner. Anyhow, in modern JS it is possible (and desired!) to do this without conditionals, and there is an elegant algorithm which allows for that by using placeholders.

Specifically we can use a `Symbol` as a stand-in for elements that are traveling within the ordered set. This way the index arithmetic is eliminated (and with it a slew of conditionals and places where off-by-one errors fester).

Works basically like this:

```
withGroupRepositioned(["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["a", "b"], 0) // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
withGroupRepositioned(["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["a", "b"], 1) // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
withGroupRepositioned(["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["a", "b"], 2) // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
withGroupRepositioned(["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["a", "b"], 3) // [ 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd' ]
withGroupRepositioned(["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["b", "a"], 2) // [ 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd' ]
withGroupRepositioned(["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["b", "a"], 3) // [ 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd' ]
withGroupRepositioned(["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["a", "c"], 4) // [ 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c' ]
```

and the entire function is:

```
const PLACEHOLDER = Symbol();
function withGroupRepositioned(inOrderedSet, valuesToReposition, toIndex) {
  // Do not damage the given set
  const cpy = [].concat(inOrderedSet);

  // Step 1. Replace all traveling elements with placeholders, in place.
  valuesToReposition.forEach((v) => cpy[cpy.indexOf(v)] = PLACEHOLDER);

  // Step 2. Reinsert values as a group, where we want them.
  cpy.splice(toIndex, 0, ...valuesToReposition);

  // Step 3. Remove placeholders.
  return cpy.filter((v) => v !== PLACEHOLDER);
}
```

The first array copy operation can be removed if you want to perform the rearrangement in-place.